# How to get Flexbox item "main" to let "aside" float next to it?

Tags: css, layout, flexbox

In the example below I am tryin to get the "summary" section to let the second aside float to the right of it on my "papa-bear" breakpoint but am having trouble, Anytime I change the flex basis or width it ends up moving to the top row and "header" aside-1 aside-2 and summary all split one row equally.

[View here on codepen](http://codepen.io/Vince_Brown/pen/eDcrs)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear on your question, but it sounds like you are wanting to put the two summary questions side-by-side at 'papa-bear'.

If so, you need to change

```
flex-direction: column
```

to

```
flex-direction: row
```

at your 'papa-bear' breakpoint.

Comment: Thank you sorry i was not clear at first, but I changed the flex direction to column because what i am trying to do is get the aside-2 to float next to the summary like aside 1 is floated next to the header at the "papa-bear" breakpoint. Any ideas about that? thank you!

Comment: I think to use flexbox for that scenario, the summary and aside would need to be children of the same element.